# How to debug a Rhodes application

Tags: android, ruby, rhodes

I have adopted Rhodes recently & I was wondering how to debug a Rhodes application. For example in Ruby we can see the line-by-line execution of code using `irb`. Also after creating the models in a Rhodes application, I want to see the database structure because I prefer to use the SQLite Manager as a Firefox plugin for my Rails apps.

I need to really see how the models look in the databases and how the attributes are stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RhoStudio (built on top of Eclipse), you can set breakpoints and step through the Ruby controllers and models ([source](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhostudio.tutorial#using-the-debugger))

To see the database structure, you can access the file system and get the database's path, and save the SQLite database off in a web service or some other means (maybe to the SD card?) to view in your Firefox plugin, the following being an example of how to get the path to the database.

```
db_path = Rho::RhoFSConnector::get_db_fullpathname('app')   # can be app, user, or local
```

**EDIT**

Or, if you build to RhoSimulator from within RhoStudio, you can navigate to the "bin" directory for RhoSimulator and inspect the SQLite files there.

`/path/to/app/rhosimulator/db`

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, do I need to add this line in the main app controller?

Comment: That gives you the file path to the database within your application's "sandbox".  You can then use that path to send the file to a web-service or the "SD card" (in quotes because it depends if you're running this on a device or emulator.) Another option is to run the application in RhoSimulator from RhoStudio, and navigate to where the SQLite files are stored - /path/to/app/rhosimulator/db